# ClosedChannelException on Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to build a TCP/IP sniffer for android using VpnService.I modified ToyVpn example I am correctly getting the output IP packet from the descriptor and for the moment I am just trying to send it to the destination socket without IP and TCP headers and show in Log the response from the destination server. Actualy, what I have to do is to deliver the packet in the network and when I have a response write it in the OutputStream coresponding to the ParcelFileDescriptor.

I am using this code:

```
while (vpnInterface != null && vpnInterface.getFileDescriptor() != null
            && vpnInterface.getFileDescriptor().valid()) {

        packet.clear();

        // Read the outgoing packet from the input stream.
        final byte[] data = packet.array();

        int length = in.read(data);

        //use this to get the unsigned byte 
        int[] d = new int[data.length];

        if (length > 0) {
            packet.limit(length);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                d[i] = data[i] & 0xFF;
                sb.append(d[i] + " ");
            }
            Log.i("packet", sb.toString());
            Socket socket = SocketChannel.open().socket();
            if ((null != socket) && (null != this)) {
                this.protect(socket);
            }

            //connect to dest ip and port
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(d[16] + "." + d[17] + "."
                    + d[18] + "." + d[19], (d[22] * 256) + d[23]));

            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream());

            dOut.write(data, 40, data.length - 40);
            dOut.flush();
            dOut.close();

            length = dIn.read(data);

            if (length > 0) {
                sb = new StringBuilder("");
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    d[i] = data[i] & 0xFF;
                    sb.append(d[i] + " ");
                }
                Log.i("response", sb.toString());
                dIn.close();
            }
        }

        Thread.sleep(10); 
}
```

The problem is that I get ClosedChannelException when trying to read the InputStream from the socket. Do you have any ideea why is this happening? The ideea is that I don't know how to manage the input packets from the dest socket.

Sorry if I made any mistake but I am beginner in JAVA.

Comment: The `socket` cannot possibly be null at the point you are testing it. If the socket couldn't be created an exception would have been thrown. And `this` can never be null at all. Don't waste time and space on pointless tests. There are more than enough real failure conditions to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

You're closing the `InputStream` that you've got from the `Socket`. JavaDoc says:

> Closing the returned InputStream will close the associated socket.

Usually, you should never close a stream that you do not own!

The same is true for the `OutputStream` you get with `socket.getOutputStream()`. If you close it, the socket will be closed too!

Comment: I tested the code with the if commented and still get the exception. It is thrown on length = dIn.read(data). Maybe is because I close the OutputStream. I will test tomorow to see.

Comment: You're closing the outputstream with dOut.close(). This closes the Socket too!

Comment: Do I have to add any header in the data that i send through the socket or it is ok like this. I ask this because I get a unintelligible response(an array of 1068 bytes) that are not an Ip packet or a tcp one. Thx!

Comment: @user3041210 Sorry, can't help in this case; I don't know the VPN protocol stack.

Comment: Ok. But is not about the VPN protocol. I write the payload of a packet in the google.com socket and I receive a bunch of bytes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379320/the-meaning-of-the-byte-array-read-from-socket